# How do I make this query work?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query this, but it somehow does not work. Is there anyone that sees what I'm doing wrong? It does seem to connect to the database but somehow it won't update the table.

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

if (isset($_REQUEST['disable'])){
$number = $_REQUEST['disable'];
$sql = "UPDATE aanwezigheid SET value='0' WHERE id='"$number"'";
mysql_query($sql);
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Does not work" is not helping much... which error(s) do you get?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Not withstanding, you have missed two `.` out surrounding `$number`

Comment: @DaveRandom Damn that was it, thanks!

Comment: You should also use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) when handling request data, and also read the comment above about using MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: -1. Read this first: [How to Fix the Typical "My PHP Script Does Not Work" Problem](http://911-need-code-help.blogspot.com/2012/11/fix-the-php-script-does-not-work-problem.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  UPDATE aanwezigheid SET value=0 WHERE id='".$number."'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is wrong. There was unwanted extra double quotes. Try this

```
$sql = "UPDATE aanwezigheid SET value='0' WHERE id='$number'";
```

Other: Don't use `mysql_*` functions. for more, see `@DaveRandom` above comment.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot two points around your variable in the query. Code should be..

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
if(isset($_REQUEST['disable'])){
    $number = $_REQUEST['disable'];
    $sql = "UPDATE aanwezigheid SET value='0' WHERE id='".$number."'";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: Accept answer if this helped you out please